How to give each element of an array of ojects a key
If I have an array that looks like:
arr =[ { id: 'f794',label: 'Blue Bird' } ]
how do I give the element of it a key so I get
arr =["myKey":{ id: 'f794',label: 'Blue Bird' } ]
I have tried several different ways, like
arr[0]= '"myKey"' + ":" + arr[0]
which gives me
[ "myKey:[object Object]" ]
How do I get arr =["myKey":{ id: 'f794',label: 'Blue Bird' } ]
Thanks

Arrays don't have keys; Objects have keys, so you'll need to use curly braces, rather than square brackets.

Will your array only ever have one element? If so, what determines the key name?

What about arr = {"myKey":arr[0]};?

You can do :
arr = arr.map((element) => {
   return ({"myKey" : element})
})

With perhaps a specific key for each element depending on what you want to do with it.

if you really want to return an object, you need to return a wrapped object in parentheses. otherwise it would read the curly brackets as function body.

or just arr.map(myKey => ({ myKey })); with short hand property.

@NinaScholz, do you really need to wrap the object in parentheses in return {"myKey" : element}? return {"myKey" : element} is fine; it should return an object literal with no problem. The shorthand form you've suggested, however, does need parentheses.

@PeterKA, by using return, it works without. in arrow functions with immediate return (without function block) you need wrap to get an expression as return value.

Here is how:


let arr = [{ id: 'f794',label: 'Blue Bird' }];

arr = arr.map( myKey => {
   return { myKey };
});

console.log( arr );



Or the shorthand equivalent:


let arr = [{ id: 'f794',label: 'Blue Bird' }];

arr = arr.map( myKey => ({ myKey }) );

console.log( arr );



